# Error #1009: null object reference - When adding a DataGrid to a ActionScript Mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm very new to ActionScript, so please forgive me if I've made any obvious mistakes here.

I'm attempting to put together a very simple ActionScript Mobile project in Flash Builder 4.7, which uses a Data Grid (`fl.controls.DataGrid`) to display a set of data.

However, when I add the DataGrid object into the 'view' (using `addChild(myDataGrid);`) I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at fl.containers::BaseScrollPane/drawBackground()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\containers\BaseScrollPane.as:1139]
at fl.controls::DataGrid/draw()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\controls\DataGrid.as:1663]
at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\core\UIComponent.as:1524]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/internalCompleteInitialWindowSetup()
at runtime::SimulatedContentPlayer/completeSimulatedInitialWindowSetup()
at runtime::SimulatedMobileDeviceContentPlayer/doCompleteInitialWindowSetup()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/completeInitialWindowSetup()
at runtime::AppRunner/onComplete()
```

From what I've managed to find out about the error, it seems to be related to missing Flash control references, but as far I can tell, I've included all of the Flash User Interface components in the *Source Path* for the project.

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface
```

I've also tried adding (and removing) a *Library Path* to the flash.swc file, which made no difference.

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe\Flash CC\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs\flash.swc
```

Is it actually possible to use this control in this project type (ActionScript Mobile)? If so, does anyone have any ideas on which libraries may still be missing, or any other mistakes I may have made?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Often times when I've encountered strange problems like this, it was because the libs were included twice and the class definition collided, expecially when using external swf/swcs as resources. Although you do mention removing one...

Comment: If you're not sure if it's the datagrid that's the culprit, you could just create a new project with only the datagrid and see if you have problems when the other libs are not involved

Comment: Thanks for the input Helto, I'd done exactly what you'd suggested, re creating an empty project, and adding only a DataGrid, with the same result sadly. I'll carry on googling and adding / removing references for now and see where I get to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up attempting to use visual Flex controls in the ActionScript mobile project, as while some Flex libraries worked (I used some to call & process web services successfully), using Flex UI controls in actionscript mobile eventually seemed too much like forcing a square peg into a round hole.

Hence, in the end I used http://feathersui.com/ for UI components, as we'd decided to base the main part of the app on Starling, and so far, it's worked out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try if possible rebuilding in CS6. I'm trying to resolve a similar random error
'Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference'

and I can only surmise that CC is the culprit.

If rebuilding in CS6 solves your problem, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as far as I know, don't think it's down to CC vs CS6. Having learned a little more about Flash development now, I think this error message is a generic description that could be caused by any number of different underlying problems.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the DataGrid component to the library fixed a similar-looking error for me, where adding a stock datagrid would fail at runtime with

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.containers::BaseScrollPane/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::DataGrid/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()

I don't know why, and I can't imagine the nest of horrors behind the scenes that make it necessary - but HTH.